# mobile site to work offline and sync changes once connection established

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, local-storage, offline

I am currently developing a mvc4 application that needs to work on mobile browsers.

One of the requirements I have for it is that if the device cant connect to the internet, the site should still "work", and any changes get sync'd to the server once an internet connection is reestablished.

The site is an ecommerce site so I would be looking at such functionality as adding items to a shopping cart etc.

I had looked at html5 local storage to manage the changes when the app is offline but not sure if that storage will exist across multiple pages of just a single page. Can anyone confirm? I plan in storing the page on the clients device by using a cache manifest file.

I would like some pointers as to how I can achieve a site to work offline and once a conneection is establish, changes syncd to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript events to detect online/offline state (search in safari docs) - with jquery (not jquery mobile), i would use the "single page application" model (link below), i would store website and user data data in local storage, and use a timer to try to push/get changes.

Single page application with MVC4:
http://www.asp.net/single-page-application

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately single page application is not an option for me. I see the benefit of it in this instance.